# Why internet not connecting in AWS EC2 windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having an AWS EC2 instance **(Instance1)** running. I want to connect the db which is running in another EC2 instance **(Instance2)** from the application hosted in this instance **(Instance1)** . but which is not getting connected. Since internet not working in this instance **(Instance1)**

Earlier it worked but now not working. I made some changes later on windows firewall on Inbound and outbound rules to enable my tomcat port 8080.

What i need to configure to make this work?

Comment: Try adding nameservers 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolve.conf . Then do ping google.com

Comment: where i can find /etc/resolve.conf file. Its a windows instance

Comment: Sorry I thought Ubuntu , what does ping google.com returns?

Comment: Request timeout. Also tried google.com in the browser. But now working

Comment: Earlier it worked.Not working only after firewall change

Answer (score 0):

Internet wont be required for Instance1 to access Instance2 if both are in same VPC. Please check the following and confirm.

1. Is Instance1 and Instance2 on same VPC?
2. Is your database binding to the private ip of your instance2?
3. Is database listen port open to be accessed from Instance1 as per the security 
   group configuration of Instance2?

Let me know in case you need help with any of the above 3 steps